# Problem when trying to create a digital ocean app from github

Tags: python, github, deployment, server, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy a python program on  digital ocean, i've created a digital ocean app, and when i try to create resource from github, i get this message:

**`no component detected`**

What can i do to solve this issue?